# borderless button in visual basic.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

HEY there I was asking about how to make a borderless button in vb.net I can always set the style to flat and make the background color as transparent but always I always get the button focused and shows in a shape of a button which ruins my button style that I want it
here is a class I used earlier but it didn't work

```
Public Class ButtonEx
Inherits Button

    Private _ShouldShowFocus As Boolean = False
    Public Property ShouldShowFocus() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ShouldShowFocus
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _ShouldShowFocus = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowFocusCues() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ShouldShowFocus
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, or anything else? Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: yea i am using Windows forms

Comment: I have added the appropriate tag. Please do make sure to indicate such information via tags in future questions; the various UI toolkits available for VB.NET are quite fundamentally different, and without said tags, people knowing about such a toolkit have no chance of finding your question.

Comment: thanks but still can't find a solution

Comment: Focus cues are not what you think they are, they are the lines under the mnemonics for the button.  It is the focus rectangle you see.  It tells the user that pressing the space bar operates the button.  You'll need to override OnPaint() to draw your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass the standard button and override the OnPaint method to achieve a borderless button.

```
Class BorderlessButton
Inherits Button

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal pe As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(pe)
    pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(BackColor, 5), ClientRectangle)
End Sub

End Class
```

I'm assuming you've tried out the `Button.FlatAppearance` properties and none of these help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class ButtonNoFocusCues
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowFocusCues As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use label that is clickable so it will be no border just add hover code.....

Also you can use bootstrap or css if your using asp.net